# Eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the linear operator T

Tags: linear-algebra

How can I solve the following exercise?

Let the linear operator $T:P_{3}\rightarrow P_{3}$ defined by

$T\left ( a_{0}+a_{1}x +a_{2}x^{2}+a_{3}x^{3}\right )=-2a_{0}-2a_{1}x +\left ( 8a_{1}-4a_{2}+2a_{3} \right )x^{2} +\left ( 7a_{1}+a_{2}-3a_{3} \right )x^{3} $

Determine the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the linear operator $T$

Thanks for your help

Comment: Find the matrix of $T$ w.r.t to the canonical basis of $P_3$ in both domain and codomain.

Comment: By inspection, constant polynomials are eigenvectors with eigenvalue $-2$.

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* Write the matrix of $T$ with respect to the canonical basis $1,x,x^2,x^3$.